# How to filter Gazebo log output

Tags: gazebo

For testing purposes, I am running Gazebo sim (i.e. 'new Gazebo') with logging enabled:

```
gz sim -v 4 world.sdf
```

This works, but there's a lot of irrelevant debug output (e.g. `gui`, `simulationrunner`, `SystemManager`, etc).

Is there a way to filter the log output?

In other words: is there an equivalent command for Gazebo sim, to following ROS 2 command:

```
ros2 run <package> <executable> --ros-args --log-level DEBUG --log-level rcl:=INFO
```

which configures loglevel 'debug' for all loggers, except for the rcl logger which gets loglevel 'info' (and hence does not output (many) messages).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe there's only a global setting (`-v 4`). One thing that might be useful is that you can run the server and the gui in two separate terminals with `gz sim -s -v4 world.sdf` and `gz sim -g` respectively with different verbosity flags.

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for, but the suggestion to run in separate terminals is relevant. In the end I resorted to using regular `std::cout` instead of `gzdbg` since the white `cout` output contrasts with the other (colored) messages. Another possibility (which I did not try) could be to use bash color codes in the log messages.